# Button that makes changes to information within database

Tags: php, sql, database, database-connection

I am writing PHP code for a web page that displays the first and last name of someone and the prayer request that was submitted for them. The idea of the page is that an admin can come in and edit the prayer request to correct typos, misspelled words, etc. I am getting the database to populate the fields no problem. The problem I am having is that when I click the "Approve Prayer Request" button I receive a "page not found" error and the info that I edited does not update within the database. Any suggestions would be extremely helpful. Thanks.

This file is named ApproveDenyPrayerRequest.

```
<?php

$username="XXXXX";
$password="XXXXX";
$database="XXXXX";

$link = mysqli_connect('XXXXXXX', $username, $password, $database);

if (!$link) {
die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . "\n";

$query = "SELECT * FROM Request";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query); //<----- Added link
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

?>

<form method="post" action="ApproveDenyPrayerRequest.php" />

<table>

<tr>
    <td>First Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="first" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_F_Name]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Last Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="last" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_L_Name]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Prayer Request</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_Request]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

</table>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Approve Prayer Request">

</form>
```

Here's the second CGI file which contains the actual mySQLi calls. This file is named PrayerRequest

```
<?php

$username="XXXX";
$password="XXXXXXX";
$database="prayer";

mysqli_connect('hostname',$username,$password,$database);
@mysqli_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "SELECT * FROM Request";
$query2="UPDATE Request (Reg_F_Name,Reg_L_Name,Reg_Request)";
VALUES ("$row[Reg_F_Name]","$row[Reg_L_Name]","$row[Reg_Request]")
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<form method="post" action="ApproveDenyPrayerRequest.php" />

<table>

<tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="first" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_F_Name]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Last Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="last" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_L_Name]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Prayer Request</td>
<td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_Request]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Comment: ensure the path to the script is right, you're calling it from a relative perspective.

Comment: The code to the file you see above is in the cgi-bin already named ApproveDenyPrayerRequest. I tried making some revisions but no luck still.

Answer (score 0):

We need to know to directory structure. For this script to be working you need to create a folder called "cgi-bin" at the same level as this script file and then you need to place "ApproveDenyPrayerRequest.php" in that folder.

if cgi-bin is already exist you need to supply the correct path i.e. if it is one lvl up try: "../cgi-bin/ApproveDenyPrayerRequest.php" or just use the absolute URL

Comment: I am new at PHP so I will attempt to describe this as best as I can. The cgi-bin already exists and the code to the file is in the cgi-bin already. The name of the file for the code you see above is named ApproveDenyPrayerRequest. I tried making some revisions but no luck still.

Comment: Here is the second CGI file named prayer request which contains the mySQL calls:

Comment: try to change:
"/cgi-bin/ApproveDenyPrayerRequest.php"
to 
"ApproveDenyPrayerRequest.php"

if both files are in cgi-bin folder then that correction will work. I suspect both are in that folder

Comment: try to use the absolute URL if the relative URL making troubles for you. Absolute URL will be: `http://www.yourWebsite.com/Folder/Script.php`

Comment: Both files are within the cgi-bin folder. When I made the change you suggested when I change the last name for example and click the approve button it reverts the information back to how it was originally stored within the database. My second file I posted when I attempt to view it throws an "internal service error" I'm thinking that's where the problem lies now.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but when I hit approve all it does is replace the information I just edited and fill it back in with what is within the database for that particular person. For example when I change a person named John to Joe and hit approve, the name changes back to John.

Comment: 1-Im not sure why would you need the 1st file. 2-your second file needs to get the data from the database, which your doing but you don't specify what row you want;therefore, you cant really get all the prayers that has not been looked at. You need to add column to mark the prayer request as read or not
3-your update statement is wrong and you need a primary key to update the exact prayer you want, otherwise, it is not possible to update your edited prayer

Comment: Would it be possible to modify the first file to work and discard the second one? The first file is at least drawing information from the database. I'm at my wits end I have been working staring at this for so many hours recently.

Comment: the update statement should be something like this:

`$query2="UPDATE Request SET Reg_F_Name='".$_POST['first']."',Reg_L_Name='".$_POST['last']."',Reg_Request='".$_POST['phone']."' WHERE PrimarykeyColumn=SomeID";`

note that the $_POST['varibleName'] gets you the value in the submitted field. 

you can do everything in one file or more it depends on how you want to do it. For now because I don't know how this program workds I don't know what the first file is for

Comment: I would like to include everything into one file as much as possible. I will add the update statements and then edit the original post with the current code from the second file and scrub the first file. Thanks again for the help.