# MySQL CGI file 500 Internal Service Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-connection

I am writing PHP code for a web page that displays the first and last name of someone and the prayer request that was submitted for them. I am having a problem with this particular cgi file. Whenever I try to preview the page, it throws a 500 internal service error. I have looked at it numerous times and cannot find the problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

$username="XXXX";
$password="XXXXXX";
$database="XXXXX";

mysqli_connect('XXXX',$username,$password);
mysqli_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "SELECT * FROM Request";
$query2="UPDATE Request (Reg_F_Name,Reg_L_Name,Reg_Request)";
VALUES ("$row[Reg_F_Name]","$row[Reg_L_Name]","$row[Reg_Request]")
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<form method="post" action="ApproveDenyPrayerRequest.php" />

<table>

<tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="first" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_F_Name]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Last Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="last" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_L_Name]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Prayer Request</td>
<td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_Request]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `semicolon` `;` at a wrong place:

```
$query2="UPDATE Request (Reg_F_Name,Reg_L_Name,Reg_Request)";
VALUES ("$row[Reg_F_Name]","$row[Reg_L_Name]","$row[Reg_Request]")
```

And the `$query2` has wrong syntax to `update`. Correct it.
Perhaps your intention was to insert a new record into the table.

Change it to:

```
$query2="INSERT INTO Request (Reg_F_Name,Reg_L_Name,Reg_Request)
         VALUES ( '$row[Reg_F_Name]', '$row[Reg_L_Name]', '$row[Reg_Request]' )";
```

I suggest you to use parameterized prepared statements in send values to database.

Comment: This is what I have now:                                     $query2="UPDATE Request (Reg_F_Name,Reg_L_Name,Reg_Request")
VALUES ("$row[Reg_F_Name]","$row[Reg_L_Name]","$row[Reg_Request]")     This is still throwing the same error though.

Comment: Okay I made the change you suggested and it is telling me now that it is unable to select the database. I double checked everything and it should all be there. I must be missing something minor. Were you able to find anything?

Comment: It means that your input for `$database` was wrong. Check if such database exists.

Comment: The database definitely exists because other CGI files are able to draw information from it. Still looking further into it and comparing other CGI files code.

Comment: It might have thrown some error. See output of `$mysqli->error`.

Comment: It is working now. Will you look at this other problem I am having found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036868/button-that-makes-changes-to-information-within-database/23037051?noredirect=1#comment35196156_23037051